# Android Chrome Facebook share dialog error

Tags: android, facebook

Using Facebook's SDK in mobile web and upon launching the share dialog which works perfecting in iOS, get error `this dialog is not available on this device share` on a Galaxy S4.

Seen something similar on Galaxy S3 that says error and could not load the dialog.

Code used:

```
FB.ui({
            method: method,
            link: link,
            picture: image_url,
            name: title,
            description: fb_share_msg,
            caption: timeline_caption
        });
```

Comment: Which dialog were you trying to use?

Comment: @MingLi the share dialog

Comment: You should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ with exact repro steps (including the parameters you used), and one of our engineers will have a look.